Split sheets based on conditions in Excel
I have a code VBA excel that needs to be split into multiple sheets, however, the results returned didn't include data from column B.
Sub Split_Sheet()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim sArr(), i As Long, sMachine(), j As Long, k As Long, dArr(), n As Long
With Sheets("PFL_PRINT")
   sArr = .Range("E10", .Range("E9").End(4)).Resize(, 25).Value
End With
With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
   For i = 1 To UBound(sArr)
      If Not .Exists(sArr(i, 1)) Then .Add sArr(i, 1), ""
   Next
   sMachine = .keys
End With
For n = 0 To UBound(sMachine)
    ReDim dArr(1 To UBound(sArr), 1 To UBound(sArr, 2))
    k = 0
    For i = 1 To UBound(sArr)
        If sArr(i, 1) = sMachine(n) Then
            k = k + 1
            For j = 1 To UBound(sArr, 2)
                dArr(k, j) = sArr(i, j)
            Next
        End If
    Next
    With Sheets.Add
        .Name = sMachine(n)
        .Range("E10").Resize(k, UBound(dArr, 2)) = dArr
    End With
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


I would like to keep column E as the condition to split the sheets and expand the displayed area from column B to AD


Does this seem like the first part you need to change?  sArr = .Range("E10", .Range("E9").End(4)).Resize(, 25).Value     4 is not a valid argument value for End() - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xldirection

Yes, I've tried it, but if I change it to sArr = .Range("B10", .Range("B9").End(4)).Resize(, 25).Value, then the condition changes and it doesn't fulfill the original purpose of splitting the data based on unique values in column E.

sArr = .Range("E10", .Range("E9").End(4)).Offset(0, -3).Resize(, 28).Value then look at col #4 of the array instead of col#1

Fortunately, End(4) reaches the last cell, but as Tim mentioned in his first comment, 4 is an invalid argument. It should be xlDown.

This code splits the sheets based on Column B instead of Column E, but my expectation is to keep column E as the condition to split the sheets and expand the displayed area from column B to AD, you can see the picture I just shared that you can understand what I say
code sArr = .Range("E10", .Range("E9").End(4)).Offset(0, -3).Resize(, 28).Value

Split Data by Column Criteria into Multiple Sheets

Not tested!

Sub SplitByMachines()
    
    ' Define constants.

    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "PFL_PRINT"
    Const SRC_TOP_CRITERIA_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "E10"
    Const SRC_COPY_COLUMNS As String = "B:AD"
    Const DST_TOP_LEFT_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "B10"
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' Use 'ActiveWorkbook' if it isn't!
    
    ' Return the source values in arrays.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_NAME)
    
    Dim cArr() As Variant, sArr() As Variant, sRowsCount As Long
    
    With sws.Range(SRC_TOP_CRITERIA_CELL_ADDRESS)
        sRowsCount = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If sRowsCount < 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data
        If sRowsCount = 1 Then ' one row
            ReDim cArr(1 To 1, 1 To 1): cArr(1, 1) = .Value
        Else ' multiple rows
            cArr = .Resize(sRowsCount).Value
        End If
        sArr = .Resize(sRowsCount).EntireRow.Columns(SRC_COPY_COLUMNS).Value
    End With
    
    Dim ColumnsCount As Long: ColumnsCount = UBound(sArr, 2)
    
    ' Return the distinct values from the criteria column in an array.
    
    Dim Machine() As Variant, sRow As Long
    
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For sRow = 1 To sRowsCount ' assuming no blanks or errors!
            If Not .Exists(cArr(sRow, 1)) Then .Add cArr(sRow, 1), Empty
        Next sRow
        Machine = .Keys
    End With
    
    ' For each item in the machine array, return the matching rows
    ' at the top of the destination array and copy the resulting values
    ' to a newly added (destination) worksheet.
    
    Dim dArr() As Variant: ReDim dArr(1 To sRowsCount, 1 To ColumnsCount)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim dRowsCount As Long, m As Long, c As Long
    
    For m = 0 To UBound(Machine)
        dRowsCount = 0
        For sRow = 1 To sRowsCount
            If cArr(sRow, 1) = Machine(m) Then
                dRowsCount = dRowsCount + 1
                For c = 1 To ColumnsCount
                    dArr(dRowsCount, c) = sArr(sRow, c)
                Next c
            End If
        Next sRow
        With wb.Sheets.Add
            .Name = Machine(m) ' assuming a non-existing, valid sheet name!
            .Range(DST_TOP_LEFT_CELL_ADDRESS) _
                .Resize(dRowsCount, ColumnsCount).Value = dArr
        End With
    Next m
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    ' Inform.

    MsgBox "Data split by machines.", vbInformation

End Sub


I just posted an answer for your code, kindly help me to check it

The comments starting with assuming... tell the story: a null string ("") is not a valid sheet name. To convince yourself that this really happened, when the error occurs, press Debug and hover over Machine to see it's value. If your criteria (machine) column will have blanks you have to account for it when populating the dictionary with e.g. If Len(cArr(sRow, 1)) > 0 Then: If Not dict.Exists....

and now I will add this code
If Len(cArr(sRow, 1)) > 0 Then
If Not .Exists(cArr(sRow, 1)) Then
.Add cArr(sRow, 1), Empty
End If
to replace for If Not .Exists(cArr(sRow, 1)) Then .Add cArr(sRow, 1), Empty right?
